# How can I increment variables in Visual C++ in the format of [A1, A2, A3, ...] for a Windows Form application?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli, windows-forms-designer

I m trying to build Sudoku solver using visual C++ Windows Form. So I created the following Layout using multiple Textboxes and then converting them from String to int. But here is the problem. How do i convert 81 variables from String to variable.
[image: Image To My Layout]

Here is what i did

```
private: System::Void Button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        int j[81];
    j[0] = System::Convert::ToInt16(i1->Text);
    j[1] = System::Convert::ToInt16(i2->Text);
    j[2] = System::Convert::ToInt16(i3->Text);
    j[3] = System::Convert::ToInt16(i4->Text);
    j[4] = System::Convert::ToInt16(i5->Text);
    j[5] = System::Convert::ToInt16(i6->Text);
    j[6] = System::Convert::ToInt16(i7->Text);
    j[7] = System::Convert::ToInt16(i8->Text);
    j[8] = System::Convert::ToInt16(i9->Text);


    }
```

How can I efficiently convert 81 string variables representing Sudoku puzzle values to integer variables in a Windows Form application created using Visual C++? Currently, I am using the "Convert::ToInt16" method to convert each variable one by one, which is a heavy task. Can I use a more efficient approach, such as incrementing variable names like "i1," "i2," "i3," etc., and assigning them to an array for further calculation?

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: "Is there any better way to do this for example by increment variables names like i1 ,i2, i3 ...in and then assigning them to an array" - if this is actually .NET then you can do this, yes, using reflection. If this is a C++ object then I don't think so. But whether you can do this by reflection or have to do it by writing out all of the fields I would still do this, yes: probably build an array, or 2D array, of the textbox objects as a field in the form object.

Comment: You might also need something other than just ToInt16, since you're necessarily leaving some of the squares empty. Or are you expecting the user to type 0s for those?

Comment: Most times, such things come due to bad code design but sometimes it might be different. In such cases, I copy/paste code into Excel, complete it using auto-fill (with increment) and copy it back. This might require to add (temporarily) space (or tab) columns here and there so that Excel will split the code in sufficient columns. For this, the block edit functions of VS (or Notepad++) are good for.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this will help

```
int newArr [j.size()]= {}
int counter = 0;  
for (string x : j)
     newArr[counter++] = System::Int16::Parse(x);
```

I would store I1, I2, etc in an array just so they are easier to access instead of i1 = value, i2 = value

```
int counter = 0;
for (int x : newArr)
    i[counter++] = x;
```